# Facebook Conversion API - not receiving events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing Facebook Conversion API on server to capture sales done via a shopping cart on a different site. I call FB API from PHP code using cURL. Here is my payload:

```
[    
   {
          "event_name":"Purchase",
          "event_time":1621701565,
          "event_id":1621701565,
          "action_source":"website",
          "event_source_url":"https://www.example.com",
          "user_data":{
             "em":"f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a",
             "fn":"532eaabd9574880dbf76b9b8cc00832c20a6ec113d682299550d7a6e0f345e25",
             "ln":"9e7cd9cb5a63a3591e16f4d835f32a1c4a84ab66e39ae27aa448c03b66bf63e7",
             "client_user_agent":"Chrome",
             "client_ip_address":"1.2.3.4"
          },
          "custom_data":{
             "currency":"USD",
             "value":"20.00",
             "content_ids":"PQ001"
          }    
    } 
]
```

When I submit it, I am getting back this response:

```
{"events_received":1,"messages":[],"fbtrace_id":"A9n8IBhVwl5gZTB4CCvSG7q"}
```

However, I do not see the event when I look at my pixel in the Event Manager. I tried using the test_event_code parameter - same story. Did anyone encounter such problem? It looks like everything was submitted OK, but where are the events?

Comment: the same issue here

Comment: Did you find the problem? I am having similar issue.

Comment: Same issue, any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue when using a dummy user agent value and IP address. It turns out that the user data in your payload needs to contain "real" data.

In your example, the problem may be the `Chrome` value in your `client_user_agent` field.

Try using a real `client_user_agent` value (like the one below).

This payload works for me:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "TestEvent",
      "event_time": 1627574182,
      "action_source": "email",
      "user_data": {
        "em": "f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a",
        "client_ip_address": "254.254.254.254",
        "client_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "test_event_code": "TEST43514"
}
```

**Note: you'll need to update the `test_event_code` and `event_time` fields** (because the Conversions API only accepts events sent in the last 7 days)

Credit to [Matěj's answer on the Facebook Developers Community forums](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/841431599821194/) for providing a working example payload and the insight that Facebook mysteriously ignores test requests with dummy data